# What is the meaning of the cellular signal icon in Bloomberg stock data?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, stock-valuation

What is the meaning of the icons highlighted in the image below taken from today’s European Market Opening as shown on Bloomberg?

[image: bloomberg stock price cellular signal]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not related to the volume of trades of that security.

If you have access to Bloomberg, you can look at the relevant functions like `MOV` to see this icon. If you hover over it, you can see that it is called News Heat.

The official documentation defines it:

> The news heat icon indicates the level of news activity around the
> relevant company. The number of heat bars represents how much news
> activity a company is currently experiencing on the Bloomberg
> Terminal® compared to the previous 45 days, normalized on a range from
> one bar (low heat) to five bars (high heat).

For anyone with access to BBG, the direct link to the help page (may break in the future) is `{LPHP Q:0:1 1858540 <GO>}`

Answer (score 0):

That may be an indication of the amount of volume of the security that has traded.  In general, price movements in less volume are less significant that price movements with a lot of volume.